# How to make the code to accept the next word not just the first one?

Tags: c

In this code, the problem which I am facing is, it only accepts the first word which has a **comma** at the end. The file has many words with commas at the end but it is accepting the first one. For example, if I gave the option to enter your **ID card number** which is not the first word. It could be the 2nd or 3rd word in the file then how I would handle it?

**1st part**

```
#define STRING_SIZE 49
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void RemoveNewLines( char * buffer ){
   char * ptr;
   ptr = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
   if( ptr )
       * ptr = 0;
   ptr = strchr( buffer, '\r' );   // in case you see carriage returns also
   if( ptr )
       * ptr = 0;
}
```

**2nd part**

```
int main(){
  char instr[STRING_SIZE+1], string[STRING_SIZE+1];
  FILE * fr = NULL;
  int flag = 0;
  size_t length = 0;

  fr = fopen("file.csv","r");
  if( fr == NULL ){
     printf( "Unable to open file\n" );
     return 1;
  }    
  printf("Enter your name: ");
  fgets( instr, STRING_SIZE, stdin);
  RemoveNewLines( instr );

  strcat( instr, "," );     // append a comma to the user's entry
  length = strlen( instr );

  while( fgets( string, STRING_SIZE, fr ) ){
     RemoveNewLines( string );
     if( strncmp( instr, string, length ) == 0 ){
        flag = 1;
        break;   }   }
  fclose(fr);      

  if( flag == 1 )   // I prefer positive logic{
     printf( "Your details :" );
     printf( "'%s'\n", string  );
     return 0;
  }
  printf("Access denied.\n");
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are comparing the beginning of a line in the file with whatever that was provided plus a `,` appended. So it is really what you asked it to do.

If you want to search on arbitrary fields, rather than this approach, I would split the line read from the csv, and compare the nth field with what was provided. Assuming this csv file is a basic one (no quotes or embedded commas/new-lines), you can easily do that by performing N `strtok()` operations on `string`.

Comment: Hey angel, I want it to take the next word after in a line. But it is taking the only first word from the line.